# SignalR doesn't work in WebForm

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2015, webforms, signalr

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 to develop an asp.net webform. I'm new to SignalR and I'm trying to get the demo piece to work in an existing site. When I create an html page it works fine:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>SignalR Simple Chat</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .container {
            background-color: #99CCFF;
            border: thick solid #808080;
            padding: 20px;
            margin: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <input type="text" id="message" />
        <input type="button" id="sendmessage" value="Send" />
        <input type="hidden" id="displayname" />
        <ul id="discussion"></ul>
    </div>
    <!--Script references. -->
    <!--Reference the jQuery library. -->
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <!--Reference the SignalR library. -->
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
    <script src="signalr/hubs"></script>
    <!--Add script to update the page and send messages.-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            // Declare a proxy to reference the hub.
            var chat = $.connection.ChatHub;
            // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
            chat.client.broadcastMessage = function (name, message) {
                // Html encode display name and message.
                var encodedName = $('<div />').text(name).html();
                var encodedMsg = $('<div />').text(message).html();
                // Add the message to the page.
                $('#discussion').append('<li><strong>' + encodedName
                    + '</strong>:&nbsp;&nbsp;' + encodedMsg + '</li>');
            };
            // Get the user name and store it to prepend to messages.
            $('#displayname').val(prompt('Enter your name:', ''));
            // Set initial focus to message input box.
            $('#message').focus();
            // Start the connection.
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
                    // Call the Send method on the hub.
                    chat.server.send($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());
                    // Clear text box and reset focus for next comment.
                    $('#message').val('').focus();
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

However, when I use the same code, in the same project, but using a WebForm it gives me an error message: 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'ChatHub' of undefined or null reference. I've been blowing an entire day on trying to get SignalR going and I'm at a loss.

Here's the code that blows up:

```
     <%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/Site.Master" CodeBehind="WebForm2.aspx.vb" Inherits="RealtimeReportsWF.WebForm2" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <div class="container">
        <input type="text" id="message" />
        <input type="button" id="sendmessage" value="Send" />
        <input type="hidden" id="displayname" />
        <ul id="discussion"></ul>
    </div>
    <!--Script references. -->
    <!--Reference the jQuery library. -->
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <!--Reference the SignalR library. -->
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
    <script src="signalr/hubs"></script>
    <!--Add script to update the page and send messages.-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            // Declare a proxy to reference the hub.
            var chat = $.connection.ChatHub;
            // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
            chat.client.broadcastMessage = function (name, message) {
                // Html encode display name and message.
                var encodedName = $('<div />').text(name).html();
                var encodedMsg = $('<div />').text(message).html();
                // Add the message to the page.
                $('#discussion').append('<li><strong>' + encodedName
                    + '</strong>:&nbsp;&nbsp;' + encodedMsg + '</li>');
            };
            // Get the user name and store it to prepend to messages.
            $('#displayname').val(prompt('Enter your name:', ''));
            // Set initial focus to message input box.
            $('#message').focus();
            // Start the connection.
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
                    // Call the Send method on the hub.
                    chat.server.send($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());
                    // Clear text box and reset focus for next comment.
                    $('#message').val('').focus();
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I slept on it and had to remember the golden rule of frameworks like SignalR... it's just java. I then realized I didn't include the ../ in the path. Makes sense since on the HTML version it was contained in the path. So modifying the code to include this solved the problem:

```
    <!--Script references. -->
    <!--Reference the jQuery library. -->
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <!--Reference the SignalR library. -->
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
    <script src="../signalr/hubs"></script>
```